# Broadcast Upload Extension invoked by RPSystemBroadcastPickerView - get extension reference?

Tags: ios, swift, ios-extensions, broadcasting

I have implemented Broadcast Upload Extension in our app. I am offering it to user through `RPSystemBroadcastPickerView` from my container app with preferredExtension set to our extension.

This is all working nicely. However now in my container App I would like to get a reference to that running Broadcast Upload Extension so from my container app I can react to the broadcast being started or stopped. How would I obtain such reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not possible, ended up communicating between the container app and the extension through **App Groups** and their **NSUserDefaults** (adding observer for keys).

Comment: u can using wormhole

Answer (score -1):

**Wormhole** doesn't receive communicate continuously. When we stop broadcasting it does through message that time.